# Precedents for Attack on Lawyer in Court and Response from the Judge

Tags: lawyer, injury

I watched the classic Liar Liar Movie and also the breakdown by a youtuber Legal Eagle where he noted in the case where the lawyer injured himself to look wounded and get relief that the entire court house would have gone into lockdown and a search would have started for the assailant. He also said that the judge would have not asked him to continue like he did in the movie.

Has there ever been such a case in real life? I would really like to look up any such cases

Comment: I'm not sure I can figure out what counts as similar or not in real life. Are there cases where lawyers lie in court to gain some kind of advantage? Sure. There are lots of cases discussing the ethical rule prohibiting it to illustrate it. To create mass havoc? Maybe (the case law on mistrial might have examples). False police reports? Maybe. But, I'm not sure what the essential features you are trying to capture here are.

Comment: @ohwilleke Basically a case where a Lawyer was injured inside the court premises for gains by the other party and how the judge and the court institution responded as a whole. I am not really trying to look for some essential feature rather I am looking to read up some interesting articles.